# for every value in given cell, locate and highlight the same value in data

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements, highlight

The current formula I'm using is as follows:

```
Columns("D:D").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=$D1='General Profiling'!$B$6"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
```

However at times, there may be values in C6, D6, etc which I also wish for the conditional formatting to pick up and highlight.

Is there a way to identify whether a value has been put in between C2 to C100 and then highlight these values on a different spreadsheet?

Comment: Should be: Is there a way to identify whether a value has been put in between B6 to Z6 and then highlight these values on a different spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid using [Range .Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197597.aspx) and [Range .Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221681.aspx) methods¹.

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).EntireColumn
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
                            "=COUNTIF('General Profiling'!$B$6:$Z6, $D1)")
            .Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End With
    End With
End With
```

This would be even better if you could change that [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx) to the name or codename of the [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx).

---

.¹ <sub>See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.</sub>

Comment: @ Jeeped: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, it seems a common thing with conditional formatting that where the value of the comparison cell is empty, the formula highlights all rows of the empty cell. Is there a way to exclude empty cells in this instance?